# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS black screen after suspension on Dell

Tags: 16.04, dell, suspend, power-management, lock-screen

I have a Dell Inspiron 15R with Intel® Ivybridge Mobile Graphics. I upgraded to Ubuntu vanilla and the latest version (16.04) few days back. Each time I close the laptop lid with the power source plugged in, and reopen it, a blank screen appears. A forced restart using the hardware button is necessary at this point. 
If the lock screen is activated, after a time it goes black.  Even when on plugged on or on battery, if unused or locked, the same happens and a manual reboot is required for it to start. The CPU is running but I cant get to the login screen

Comment: @Videonauth This question is wrongly marked as a duplicate! The linked question asks about not being able to suspend by closing the lid. This one asks about blank screen after resuming.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to match something I've seen already for 14.04:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xubuntu-default-settings/+bug/1303736

File a new bug, and for now try the workaround from [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xubuntu-default-settings/+bug/1303736/comments/118):

> map some key combination to:
>   `xrandr --auto`
>   and you'll get your screen back by pressing it.